# Get number of online users (I add users to database)

Tags: asp.net

I create a table in database add users to database and when users login to website i add their code to `Session` now how can i get number of users that online and get their code ?

i use below code but doesn't work

```
MembershipUserCollection users= Membership.GetAllUsers();
int a=Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Solution can be to create a New Application Variable. You can make a collection variable and add users when they log into your application (with `Session_start()` method) and remove them when session timed out (`Session_end()`). These two methods are in the Global.asax file

The point is the delay. Users will be removed at session_end so it will be a delay between "browser closure" and session time out. This delay will be equal to the session life time for your application.

Comment: this method has a problem : the method "Session_end()" call when we clear Session but if user close the browser this method doesn't call and i can't recognize that user is offline

Comment: That's exactly why I wrote about the 'Delay'. Session_end is always trigged but after the session time out (time depending of your application configuration)

Comment: you mean if user close browser the method "Session_end()" call for example after 20 min ?

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad Yes, that's what I mean. I did this trick before and it worked well